# Get the value of Label in listview

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, listview

I have a listview with invisible label to store the category Id.
what I want to do is to assign the text of the label to a cookie or session on button click.
the problem is my cookie is always null when I try to display the value outside the listview.
here is my aspx code:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="catListView" DataSourceID="CategoriesDataSource" >
            <EmptyDataTemplate>No DataFound</EmptyDataTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="service" style="margin-bottom:10px;width:230px;">               
                     <h4 style="font-family:Corbel;" ><%#Eval("CatName") %></h4>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Visible="false" ID="lblcat"><%#Eval("CatId") %></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnTest" Text="View Items" OnClick="btnTest_Click" />
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

my C# code:

```
protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Cookies["cat"].Value = "test";
            foreach (ListViewItem item in catListView.Items)
            {
                Label catLabel = (Label)item.FindControl("lblcat");
                Response.Cookies["cat"].Value = catLabel.Text.ToString();
            }

        }
```

any help will be appreciated.
thx in advance

Sam

Comment: How are you trying to display it outside the `ListView`?  Also, catLabel.Text is a string, no need to call `.ToString()` on it =)

Comment: @jadarnel27 Like this in aspx page:
<%=Request.Cookies["cat"].Value %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your ListView might not be databound when your Button click event is called.

I would recommend that you use [the ItemCommand event handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3).  It is most appropriate for this type of handling.  Update your ListView declaration to handle that event:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="catListView" DataSourceID="CategoriesDataSource
    OnItemCommand="catListView_ItemCommand" >
```

*Note: Don't forget to remove the "OnClick" event handler from the Button*

And then write your even handler code like this:

```
protected void catListView_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Label catLabel = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblcat");
    Session["currentCatLabelText"] = catLabel.Text;
}
```

This also has the advantage of not looping through all your ListView items, but just looking at the one you clicked.

Comment: thank you, i thought about this before posting my question.
but I have another code for OnClick event, could I add it to listview?
seems to be stupid question, but i really didn't use Itemcommand before.

Comment: @Samira I don't understand what you mean.  You don't need to get rid of all your OnClick events.  But if something is inside the ListView, you should probably use ItemCommand.

Comment: you said I should remove Onclick event handler from the button. Sorry I thought I have to remove the event not the code related to ListView.
thanks for your help, I will try it :)

Comment: @Samira Oh, I see!  Thanks for explaining.  Well, you can remove the OnClick event from the code behind if you want.  It won't do anything once you remove the `OnClick="btnTest_Click"` from the Button markup.

Comment: @Samira I'm glad that worked for you!  Sorry about forgetting to cast the object back to a Label - that was a silly mistake on my part =)  I was just freetyping that in the answer box, so I didn't test it.

Comment: thanks @jadarnel27 I just want to add a small thing:
I used ItemCommand without removing Onclick for button, no prob. till now and replaced cookie with session.
Cookies work but session works better for me
thx again 

Sam

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps :)

```
string[] catvals = new string[catListView.Items.Count];

            for (int i =0; i< catListView.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                Label catLabel = (Label)catListView.FindControl("lblcat");
                catvals[i] = catLabel.Text;
            }
            for(int i = 0 ; i < catvals.Length; i++)
            {
                Response.Cookies["cat"+ i.ToString()].Value = catvals[i].ToString();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are trying to add your `cat` in one key. I mean you are overwriting values in loop.

You should change your code in this way:

In your C# code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack == false)
        {
            HttpCookie testCokkie = new HttpCookie("ExampleCookie");
            testCokkie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5);
            Response.Cookies.Add(testCokkie);

        }
    }



 protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie ExampleCookie = Request.Cookies["ExampleCookie"];
        int tempIndex = 0;
        foreach (ListViewItem item in catListView.Items)
        {
            Label catLabel = (Label)item.FindControl("lblcat");
            ExampleCookie["cat" + tempIndex.ToString()] = catLabel.Text.ToString();
            tempIndex = tempIndex + 1;
        }
    }
```

**TO read this cookie**

```
HttpCookie exampleCookie = Request.Cookies["ExampleCookie"];
if (exampleCookie != null)
{
    int tempIndex = 0;
    foreach (ListViewItem item in catListView.Items)
    {
        Response.Write("<br/>" + exampleCookie["cat" + tempIndex.ToString()]);
        tempIndex = tempIndex + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, I didn't try the code yet but I have just a comment.
I  don't want to display the cookie in response.write, I will use it as parameter in my Procedure in database. want just to display to make sure it's not null!
So I could assign it to a label in read cookie?